# Angular - MatForm Validator personalizado não funciona

Tags: angular

Tenho o seguinte código no constructor do meu componente:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  id_periodo_ini: new FormControl(undefined),
  id_periodo_fim: new FormControl(undefined)
})
```

No `ngAfterContentInit()` eu tento adicionar um Validator personalizado:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {

    this.form.get('id_periodo_ini').setValidators([
      Validators.required,
      this.periodoService.comparaPeriodo(
        this.form.get('id_periodo_ini').value,
        this.form.get('id_periodo_fim').value
      )
    ])

    this.form.get('id_periodo_fim').setValidators([
      Validators.required,
      this.periodoService.comparaPeriodo(
        this.form.get('id_periodo_ini').value,
        this.form.get('id_periodo_fim').value
      )
    ])

}
```

No meu periodoService, o código do método `comparaPeriodo()` está assim:

```
public comparaPeriodo(periodoInicial: Periodo, periodoFinal: Periodo): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

    console.log(periodoFinal, periodoInicial)
    if (
      (periodoInicial && periodoFinal) &&
      (periodoInicial.dt_inicial && periodoFinal.dt_inicial)
    ) {
      console.log(periodoInicial, periodoFinal)

      if (periodoFinal.dt_inicial < periodoInicial.dt_inicial) {
        console.log("Invalido")
        return {
          periodoInvalido: "O período inicial deve ser anterior ao período final"
        }
      }

    }
    return null;

  }
}
```

Só que quando eu altero o valor dos campos "`id_periodo_ini`" e "`id_periodo_fim`" está SEMPRE NULL.

Já coloquei um `(selectionChange)` no `mat-select` e lá está pegando o valor correto, mas quando chama o "`comparaPeriodo()`" sempre aparece `null`.

O que mais eu tenho que fazer para colocar um validator personalizado?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro criar este validator no formGroup ao inves de criar diretamente nos formControls, e ao invés de passar os valores para seu validator, passe diretamente os formControls e extraí os valores deles.

Outra alternativa, é que seus validators estão executando antes de receber o valor, então na criação do formControl, faça da seguinte forma:

```
const control = new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'blur', validators: [seus_validators_aqui]});
```